# how to send messages from server to client when client has reconnected the server again

Tags: java

Can someone look at my code and tell me what's wrong?
I am trying to make a client server chat program and want server to accept endless connections requested from the clients. It runs successfully. At First run, server and client are able to chitchat properly but  when the client is closed(quit) and again  came  back, client is able to connect with
 server and even  it can send messages to server and messages are also received by the server BUT there is issue at server side, At Server side  server  messages  are not reach to client properly. Some messages are skipped and are not able to reached to client immediately as it was before in the first run.Please help me if anyone can find this solution.

**SERVER CODE:**

```
//packages
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    public class Server1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            // Instance variable fields
             ServerSocket listener=null; 
             Socket clientSocket=null;
            final int port = 444;

            System.out.println("Server waiting for connection on port "+port);
            try
            {
                listener = new ServerSocket(port);                                    
               // Creates a server socket bound to the specified port.
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            while(true)
            {

                try
                {

                    clientSocket = listener.accept(); //Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it.
                    //clientsocket is now the route through which we can communicate with the client.
                   //if we reach here, the server got a call already...

                    System.out.println("You have succesfully connected");
                    /*Returns local address of this serversocket and
                     Returns the remote port number to which this socket is connected. */

                    System.out.println("Recieved connection from "+clientSocket.getInetAddress() +" on port "+clientSocket.getPort());
                     new echoThread(clientSocket).start();  //new thread for a client

                }
                catch( IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("I/O error "+e);;
                }

            }
        }
    }




     class echoThread extends Thread{
     Socket clientSocket;     //  instance variable field

     //For every client we need to start separate thread.    
     public echoThread(Socket clientSocket)   //constructor
         {
               this. clientSocket = clientSocket;
            }


            //create two threads to send and recieve from client
            public void run()
            {
            RecieveFrmClientThread recieve = new RecieveFrmClientThread(this.clientSocket);
            Thread thread = new Thread(recieve);
            thread.start();
            SndToClientThread send = new SndToClientThread(this.clientSocket);
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(send);
            thread2.start();
            }
        }
     //INCOMING
    class RecieveFrmClientThread implements Runnable
    {
        Socket clientSocket=null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        public RecieveFrmClientThread(Socket clientSocket)
        {
             this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

         }   //end constructor

        public void run() {
            try{
                 br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));    
            //returns the input stream through which the server can hear the client.

            String messageString="";
            System.out.println("Please enter something to send back to client..");
            while(true){
            while((messageString = br.readLine())!= null)
            {//assign message from client to messageString
                if(messageString.equals("EXIT"))
                { 
                    System.out.println("you  have been logout from it");

                    //break;//break to close socket if EXIT
                }
                System.out.println("From Client: " + messageString);//print the message from client
            messageString=""; 

            }



            }
            }

        catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
        }
    }//end class RecieveFromClientThread

    //OUTGOING
    class SndToClientThread implements Runnable
    {
        //instance field variables
        PrintWriter pwPrintWriter;
        Socket clientSock = null;

        public SndToClientThread(Socket clientSock)
        {
            this.clientSock = clientSock;

        }
        public void run() {
            try{
                pwPrintWriter =new PrintWriter(this.clientSock.getOutputStream(),true);//returns the output stream through which the server can talk to the client,


            while(true)
            {
                String msgToClientString = null;

                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));//get input from server

                msgToClientString = input.readLine();//read message from server to send it to client
                if(msgToClientString.equals("EXIT"))
                {

                    System.out.println("Disconnecting Client!!");

                    //System.exit(0);
                }


                pwPrintWriter.println(msgToClientString);//send message to client with PrintWriter

                pwPrintWriter.flush();//flush the PrintWriter

                        }//end while


            }

            catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}   
        }//end run
    }//end class SendToClientThread




    CLIENT CODE :

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    public class Client1 {
        //Instance variable field
        //private ServerSocket ss;

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {


            try {
                Socket sock = new Socket("localhost",444);

                /*//create two threads to send and recieve from client
                RecieveFromServer recieveThread = new RecieveFromServer(sock);
                System.out.println("SOCK=" +sock);
                Thread thread2 =new Thread(recieveThread);
                thread2.start();
                SendToServer sendThread = new SendToServer(sock);
                Thread thread = new Thread(sendThread);
                thread.start();*/
                new echoThread1(sock).start();  //new thread for a client


            }

            catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());} 


    }
    }

    class echoThread1 extends Thread {
    Socket sock;
     public echoThread1(Socket sock) {
                this.sock = sock;

            }

            //create two threads to send and recieve from client

            public void run()
            {
                RecieveFromServer recieveThread  = new RecieveFromServer(this.sock);
            Thread thread = new Thread(recieveThread);
            thread.start();
            SendToServer sendThread = new SendToServer(this.sock);
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(sendThread);
            thread2.start();

            } 
        }

    class RecieveFromServer implements Runnable
    {
        Socket sock=null;
        BufferedReader recieve=null;

        public RecieveFromServer(Socket sock) {

            this.sock = sock;
        }//end constructor
        public void run() {
            try{

            recieve = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));//get inputstream for this socket
            String msgRecieved = null;
            while((msgRecieved = recieve.readLine())!= null)
            {
                System.out.println("From Server: " + msgRecieved);

            }
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
        }//end run
    }//end class RecieveFromServer
    class SendToServer implements Runnable
    {
        Socket sock=null;
        PrintWriter print=null;
        BufferedReader brinput=null;

        public SendToServer(Socket sock)
        {

            this.sock = sock;

        }//end constructor
        public void run(){
            try{

            if(this.sock.isConnected()) //Returns TRUE if the socket is successfuly connected to a server


            {
                System.out.println("Client connected to "+this.sock.getInetAddress() + " on port "+this.sock.getPort());
                this.print = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true); 
                System.out.println("Type your message to send to server..type 'EXIT' to exit");
                while(true){


                brinput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // input from client
                String msgtoServerString=null;
                msgtoServerString = brinput.readLine();
                this.print.println(msgtoServerString);
                this.print.flush();

                if(msgtoServerString.equals("EXIT"))
                {
                    System.out.println("you have logged out of server...Thanks for your visit");
                    sock.close();

                    break;}
                }
                }//end while

            }
            catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
        }//end run method
    }//end class SendToServer
```

Comment: Are there exceptions being logged?

Comment: At a first look at the code, i think you do not finish all client-side threads correctly, for examle the ReceiveFromServer-Thread. But some Exception-Messages or something like that would be helpful.

Comment: #Supahupe yes i have checked it again but couldnt resolved the issue.